# How to present frequencies and cumulative frequencies side by side (dodge position) in barchart with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am trying to present frequencies and cumulative frequencies side by side in a bar chart in ggplot but what I end up is overlapping bars.

For a reproducible example:

```
data(mtcars)
setDT(mtcars)

data <- mtcars[, .(Total = .N), by = carb][order(carb)][, .(carb, freq = Total/sum(Total))][
  , .(carb, freq, cumfreq = cumsum(freq))]

ggplot(data, aes(x = carb)) +
  geom_bar(fill = "red", alpha = 0.5, stat = "identity" , aes(y = freq), position = position_dodge()) + 
  geom_bar(fill = "blue", alpha = 0.5, stat = "identity" , aes(y = cumfreq), position = position_dodge())
```

[image]

Your advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change a little bit the data you are using, like this (with reshape2 package) :

```
library(reshape2)

new_data = melt(data,id = "carb")

ggplot(data = new_data)+aes(x = carb, y = value, fill = variable)+
  geom_bar(alpha = 0.5,stat = "identity", position = position_dodge())+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red","blue"))
```

Tell me if it's what you want

Comment: This is a fine idea and thank you.  But more generally, I am interested in being able to place bars corresponding to vectors --i.e. columns-- side by side using ggplot.  E.g. in this case the columns are freq and cumfreq.  Is there a more direct way to do it, or I should always reshape the data?

Answer (score 0):

That's a good question! It's common to just add layers when it comes to different geometry types, but I've always had to regroup/reshape the data to plot grouped/dodged bars. Nonetheless, I believe you can get what you want (no data wrangling) using plotly: https://plot.ly/~luana.marinho/114#plot. Not the most sophisticated solution, agreed, but it's fast and you can snoop into the R code there.